# glReadPixels leads to stack smashing when the width is not a multiple of 4

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to use `glReadPixels` to extract the image data via the following code:

```
   std::array<unsigned char, 3 * height * width> data;
   glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data.data());
```

The image is perfect when the width is a multiple of 4 (height seems to be arbitrary). When it is not, however, I get the runtime error:

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

So for example, the following (width,height) pairs work fine:

```
(20,20),(20,21),(20,22),(20,23),(20,24)
(24,20),(24,21),(24,22),(24,23),(24,24)
```

The following yield "stack smashing" errors:

```
(21,20),(22,20),(23,20)
```

I would guess that there is some padding going on, but I don't see any mention of it on the OpenGL website:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml

Could somebody please point me to some documentation explaining how much space I should allocate, and what the padding looks like?

Comment: Yes, the pixel bytes ARE aligned to some boundary. Usually to the next word (aka 4 bytes). You can force specific alignments by calling [glPixelStore](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPixelStore.xml) with the `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, the alignment for read operations `GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT` is set to 4 bytes. This means, that every row has to start at an address with this alignment. Since you are reading 3 bytes per pixel, you're needing more memory than expected if `(3 * width) % 4 != 0`.

You can either allocate the required amount of memory, or you can force a different alignment by calling

```
glPixelStore(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, desired_alignment);
```

As @dave noted, only 1, 2, 4 or 8 is allowed as alignment.

Comment: note that only alignments `1, 2, 4,` or `8` are allowed.